# my division are moving when pressed zoom in in css

Tags: html, css

I have created a design but when I zoom in or out the divisions are moving

Here is my css:

```
.date {
    color: #CCCCCC;
    font-family: georgia;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-style: italic;
    margin-left:67px;
}
.blank {
    background:#CCCCCC;
    width:100%;
    height:5px;
}
}
.menu {
}
.menu_item {
    margin:20 5;
    list-style:none;
    float:left;
}
.menu_item li {
    display:inline;
    margin:10px;
}
.menu_item li a {
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#ffffff;
    font-size:14px;
    font-family:Arial;
}
.menu_item li a:hover {
    color:#999999;
}
.sitelogo:hover h1 {
    color:#999999;
}
.sitelogo {
    text-decoration:none;
}
.menu_item_right li {
    display:inline;
    /*margin:10px;*/
    color:#ffffff;
    font-size:14px;
    font-family:Arial;
}
.menu_item_right li img:hover {
    opacity:1;
}
.menu_item_right li img {
    opacity:.5;
}
.menu_item_right li a {
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#ffffff;
    font-size:14px;
    font:bold;
}
.menu_item_right li a:hover {
    color:#999999;
}
h1 {
    margin:5px 0 0 0;
    color:#ffffff;
    font-size:28px;
    font-family:'PT Sans', sans-serif;
}
h3 {
    margin:10px 10px 10px 70px;
    color:#333333;
    font-size:15px;
    font-family: Arial;
}
.italic_text {
    margin-left:9px;
    float:left;
    color: #CCCCCC;
    font-family: georgia;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-style: italic;
}
.newscontent a {
    margin-left:68px;
    float:left;
    font-family:Arial;
    color:#3399cc;
    font-size:12px;
    text-decoration:none;
}
.newsmaincontent1 a {
    margin-left:10px!important;
    font-family:Arial;
    color:#3399cc;
    font-size:12px;
    text-decoration:none;
}
.newsmaincontent {
    float:left;
    font-family:Arial;
    color:#666666;
    font-size:12px;
    margin:15px 15px 28px 68px;
}
.italic_text1 {
    margin-left:10px;
    float:left;
    color: #CCCCCC;
    font-family: georgia;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-style: italic;
}
.newscontent1 h3 {
    margin:10px;
    color:#333333;
    font-size:15px;
    font-family: Arial;
}
h2 {
    margin:10px 10px 0px 0px;
    color:#333333;
    font-size:18px;
    font-family:'PT Sans', sans-serif;
}
.newscontent1 a {
    margin-left:10px;
    float:left;
    font-family:Arial;
    color:#3399cc;
    font-size:12px;
    text-decoration:none;
}
.newsmaincontent1 {
    float:left;
    font-family:Arial;
    color:#666666;
    font-size:12px;
    margin:15px 15px 28px 10px;
}
.site-title {
    margin:0 0;
    color:#dcf1ff;
    float:left;
    margin-left:10%;
}
.site_text {
    font-size:12px;
    font-family:Arial;
    color:#dcf1ff;
}
.menu_item_right {
    list-style:none;
    float:right;
    margin-right:10%;
}
.footer {
    width:100%;
    padding-top:2%;
    margin-top:2%;
    height:200px;
    background:#eaeaf7;
}
.footer_menu {
    text-align:center;
    list-style:none;
    display:inline;
    margin-left:31%;
    margin-top:10%;
}
.footer_menu_lower {
    color:#999999;
    text-align:center;
    width:38%;
    margin-left:32%
}
.footer_menu li {
    display:inline;
    margin:5px;
    font:Arial;
    font-size:15px;
    color:#999999;
}
.footer_menu li a {
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#3399cc;
}
.header {
    width:100%;
    height:60px;
    background-color:#69bef6;
    border-bottom:5px;
    color:#e6e6f3;
}
.wrap {
    margin-left:10%;
    margin-right:10%;
    width:80%;
}
.leftContent {
    width:32%;
    float:left;
    background:#f2f2f9;
    /*overflow:hidden;*/
}
.leftcontent1 {
    width:100%;
    /*padding:10px 10px 10px 10px;
    */
    float:left;
    background:#FFFFFF;
    margin-top:2%;
    /*margin:10px*/
    ;
}
.imgbtn {
    width:60px;
    height:36px;
    background-image:url(../images/dateBg.png);
    margin-top:3%;
    float:left;
}
.leftcontentgraph {
    width:100%;
    float:left;
    background:#FFFFFF;
    height:200px;
}
.rightContent {
    width:65%;
    float:right;
}
.leftcontentgraphborder {
    background:#A8CA5C;
    width:100%;
    height:5px;
}
.rightcontentupperborderblog {
    background:#A8CA5C;
    width:100%;
    height:5px;
}
.rightcontentupperborder {
    background:#5DBCD2;
    width:100%;
    height:5px;
}
.rightcontentlowerborderblog {
    background:#A8CA5C;
    width:100%;
    height:5px;
}
.rightcontentlowerpartleft1border {
    background:#5DBCD2;
    width:100%;
    height:5px;
}
.rightcontentlowerpartright1border {
    background:#5DBCD2;
    width:100%;
    height:5px;
}
.rightcontentlowerpartright1border1 {
    background:#A8CA5C;
    width:100%;
    height:5px;
}
.rightcontentlowerpartright1border3 {
    background:#5DBCD2;
    width:100%;
    height:5px;
}
.rightcontentupperpart {
    width:100%;
    float:left;
    background:#FFFFFF;
    height:300px;
}
.rightcontentlowerpart {
    width:100%;
    float:left;
    /*background:#f2f2f9;*/
}
.clear {
    clear:both;
}
.rightcontentlowerpartleft {
    width:49%;
    float:left;
}
.rightcontentlowerpartright {
    width:49%;
    float:right;
}
.rightcontentlowerpartleft1 {
    width:100%;
    float:left;
    background:#FFFFFF;
    margin-top:2%;
    /*margin:10px*/
    ;
}
.rightcontentlowerpartright1 {
    width:100%;
    float:left;
    background:#FFFFFF;
    margin-top:2%;
    /*margin:10px*/
    ;
}
}
/* for blog*/
 .blogpage {
    width:100%;
}
.leftcontentgraphborderblog {
    background:#5DBCD2;
    width:100%;
    height:5px;
}
.leftContentblog {
    width:756px;
    float:left;
}
.rightContentblog {
    width:300px;
    float:right;
}
.rightcontentupperpartblog {
    width:100%;
    float:left;
    background:#FFFFFF;
    height:300px;
}
.rightcontentlowerpartblog {
    width:100%;
    float:left;
    background:#000000;
}
.rightcontentlowerpartblogcontent {
    width:100%;
    background:#FFFFFF;
}
```

here is the html

```
<body  bgcolor="#f2f2f9" style="margin:0 auto;overflow:scroll">
    <div style="margin:0 auto; "  ><!-- main div start-->
                <!--header start-->
        <div class="header"><!--  div header start-->

            <div class="menu"><!-- div  menu start-->
                <a class="sitelogo" href="#">
                    <div class="site-title"><!--  div site-tittle start-->
                        <h1>
                            BIG DATA
                        </h1>
                        <span class="site_text"> <!--  div site text start-->
                            Powered by PureAnalyzer
                        </span>                 <!--div site text close-->
                    </div>        <!-- div site tittle close -->

                </a>

                <ul class="menu_item">
                      <li>
                        <a href="#"><b>HOME</b></a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#"><b>NEWS</b></a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#"><b>CAREERS</b></a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#"><b>BLOG</b></a>
                    </li>
                </ul>

                <ul class="menu_item_right">

                      <li>
                        <a href="#"><b>SUBSCRIBE FOR ALERTS</b></a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                            <a href="#"><img class="icon_image" src="images/facebook.png" /></a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#"><img src="images/twitter.png" /></a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#"><img src="images/googlePlus.png" /></a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#"><b>LOGIN</b></a>
                    </li>
                </ul>        
            </div>

        </div>
                <!--header ends-->
        <div class="clear"></div>
                <!--page body start-->
        <div class="wrap">
        <div class="blogpage">
                    <!--left part start-->        
            <div class="leftContentblog" >
                <H2>Blog</H2>
                <div class="leftcontentgraph">
                    <div class="leftcontentgraphborderblog"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="clear"></div>
                <div class="leftcontent1">
                    <div class="newscontent"><h3>lorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, </h3>
                        <div class="date">5Jan,2013</div>
                        <div class="newsmaincontent">
                            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,                             when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the
                        </div>
                    </div>
                   </div>
                <div class="leftcontent1">
                    <div class="newscontent"><h3>lorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, </h3>
                        <div class="date">5Jan,2013</div>
                        <div class="newsmaincontent">
                            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,                                                                                             when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="leftcontent1">
                    <div class="newscontent"><h3>lorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, </h3>
                        <div class="date">5Jan,2013</div>
                        <div class="newsmaincontent">
                            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,                             when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="leftcontent1">
                    <div class="newscontent"><h3>lorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, </h3>
                        <div class="date">5Jan,2013</div>
                        <div class="newsmaincontent">
                            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,                             when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="leftcontent1">
                    <div class="newscontent"><h3>lorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, </h3>
                        <div class="date">5Jan,2013</div>
                        <div class="newsmaincontent">
                            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,     when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="leftcontent1">
                    <div class="newscontent"><h3>lorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, </h3>
                        <div class="date">5Jan,2013</div>
                        <div class="newsmaincontent">
                        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,         when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
                    <!--left part ends-->
                    <!--right part start-->
            <div class="rightContentblog">
                <h2>CATEGORY</h2>
                <div class="clear"></div>
                <div  class="rightcontentupperpartblog">
                    <div class="rightcontentupperborderblog"></div>
                    <div class="newscontent"><h3>lorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, </h3>    
                        <div class="newsmaincontent">
                            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>

                <div class="clear"></div>

                <h2>ARCHIVE</h2>

                <div class="clear"></div>

                <div class="rightcontentlowerpartblog">
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                    <div class="rightcontentlowerpartblogcontent">
                        <div class="rightcontentlowerborderblog">
                        </div>
                        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the
                    </div>
                </div>    
            </div>
                    <!--right part ends-->
        </div>
        </div>                    
                <!--page body ends-->
        <div class="clear"></div>
                <!--footer start-->
         <div class="footer">

         </div>
                <!--footer ends-->     
    </div>
                <!-- main div ends-->
</body>
```

When I pressed zoom in all the div leave there place and this problem also occor when i pressed zoom out

Comment: if needed i will update the html code also

Comment: You are unlikely to get the help you need if you don't include your HTML.

Comment: @saby87 its a good idea to put your code to sites like http://jsfiddle.net so that we can experiment with them..
Your code is now at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/pxLyq/

Comment: Usually you will have a better chance to get the answers you're looking for, and get them faster, by making your code short and to the point. Try removing any code that isn't directly involved in the part where your problem occurs, or try making a simplified analogous code that exhibits the same problem for you.

Answer (score 0):

You should give a `min-width` to the `.blogpage` item since it contains elements of fixed width..

It should be the sum of the child elements so

```
.blogpage{min-width:1056px;}
```

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/pxLyq/1/